# How do I check if my board is connected to the internet?

Tags: wifi, esp32

Let me get this straight, I'm trying to see my ESP32 is connected to the **internet** or not, not Wi-Fi, as at times the board is able to connect to Wi-Fi, but not able to contact any servers, due to router issues.

I want to check, if the board is connected the internet or not, how do I do this?

What I have so far:-

```
char ssid[] = "Youreally";
char pass[] = "WannaKnow";

void setup(){
WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop(){
  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
  Serial.println("Connected");
  }
}
```

Comment: ping a known server

Comment: I usually ping 8.8.8.8 - Google's DNS servers.

Comment: @Majenko What is the maximum frequency allowed for those

Comment: and where can I find information about this

Comment: No idea. It's a massive cluster of globally distributed servers, and a few pings would disappear amongst the huge amount of DNS traffic.

Comment: So, I can contact it frequently without getting banned

Comment: Depends what you term "frequently". Once every few minutes or so is no problem.

Comment: What does "freaquently" mean for you? Once a second, once per hour? Isn't it enough to check right after the wifi setup? Whatever service you use on the internet would give you an error once it is not reachable...

Comment: To make Pinging easier [FabGL](https://github.com/fdivitto/FabGL/blob/master/examples/VGA/NetworkTerminal/NetworkTerminal.ino#L303) has a ping example and an [ICMP](https://github.com/fdivitto/FabGL/tree/master/src/network) class.

Comment: @Majenko Maybe around 5 seconds

Comment: 5 seconds is way too often, and short polling is not needed for low-lag detection. Just connect to any public websocket server, pass a callback to `onEvent`, listening for `WStype_DISCONNECTED` event type, upon which you can be 90% sure the internet is out. I would then use an http request to try to download my own website's robots.txt to confirm. No pinging, no policy violations or ISP consternation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you would be having some sort of connectivity except WiFi you could check that on regular basis in your loop, for instance when using MQTT I would check:

```
if (!mqttClient->connected())
```

and then based on the result I would test:

```
if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
```

so I can handle the relevant layer.